# JSP + Ajax - how to put response to variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

I have application based on JSP and DOJO/Ajax.
I need to get resposne and put it in global variable in javascript.

Here is my code (js):

```
function getNameById(id){ 
         var res;
         ViewDwr.getName(id, function(data){ 
               res = data; 
         });
        return res; 
  }
```

In ViewDwr i've method getName which return one variable - **data**

Of course it doesn't work and I don't have idea to resolve it.

I hope that it could be resove with some simple method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a global variable no need to declare variable with **var**.
The below code will create a global variable **res** with the value **data**

```
function getNameById(id)
{
//var res;
ViewDwr.getName(id, function(data){
res = data;
});
//return res;
}
```

Comment: Yes you're right, but it still doesn't work, and any trying to get value of it show me "undefined".

Comment: did you try to print(console.log or alert) the output of data/res and check whether you getting the data?

Comment: No, but if put alert(data) for "res = data" it works and i've get the message with correct value.